# What is metastable range?

Tags: definition, homotopy-theory

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#History) states that

> In 1953 George W. Whitehead showed that there is a metastable range
>   for the homotopy groups of spheres.

What is the metastable range? I was unable to find the definition.

Answer (score 2):

The metastable range refers to the existence of a long exact sequence
$$\pi_{3n-2}(S^{n}) \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow \pi_{q}(S^{n}) \rightarrow \pi_{q+1}(S^{n+1}) \rightarrow \pi_{q-1}(S^{2n-1}) \rightarrow \pi_{q-1}(S^{n}) \rightarrow \cdots$$
in the range $q \leq 3n-2$.

The relevant paper is [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969855).

Comment: (...Or one can read section 4J of Hatcher's book.)